# Microsoft Access query trying to create a table of unique sequential numbers based on date

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to create a table of unique numbers using a Form that has a text box to input the requested amount of unique numbers to be generated as well as a button to run the program.  What I have so far uses a combination of VBA and SQL (Essentially the VBA Code runs the SQL queries in a while loop). The VBA Code is as follows:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command10_Click()

'Get number of iterations
Dim i As Integer

'Ensure that Form is open
 DoCmd.OpenForm "Interface"

'Set i as value inputed into the Form
i = Forms![Interface]![Text6]

'Clear t3
 DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM t3"

'Generate as many control numbers as wanted
Do While i > 0

    'Generate Control number
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Control", acViewNormal, acEdit

    'Clean up duplicates
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Dup_Cont", acViewNormal, acEdit

    'Populate t3 with only new control numbers
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "New Numbers", acViewNormal, acEdit

    'reduce i by 1
    i = i - 1
Loop

'Open t3 as a ReadOnly table
DoCmd.OpenTable "t3", acViewNormal, acReadOnly

End Sub
```

The SQL Queries used are as follows:

"CONTROL Query"

```
INSERT INTO t1 ( DATE, DATE_NUM, CONTROL_NUMBER, UNIQUE_NUM )
SELECT DISTINCT 
'C77A' & Year(Date()) & Format(Month(Date()),'00') & Format(Day(Date()),'00') AS DATE_A, 
IIf([DATE] Like [DATE_A],Count(*)+1,1) AS DATE_NUM, 
[DATE_A] & Format([DATE_NUM],'000') AS CONTROL_NUM, 
Year(Date()) & Format(Month(Date()),'00') & Format(Day(Date()),'00') &  Format(IIf([DATE] Like [DATE_A],Count(*)+1,1),'000') AS UNIQUE_NUM
FROM t2
GROUP BY t2.DATE;
```

"Dup_Cont Query"

```
SELECT DISTINCT
t1.DATE, 
t1.DATE_NUM,
t1.CONTROL_NUMBER,
t1.UNIQUE_NUM INTO t2
FROM t1;
```

"New Numbers Query"

```
INSERT INTO t3 ( CONTROL_NUMBER )
SELECT Max(t2.CONTROL_NUMBER)
FROM t2;
```

What this code does currently is it creates a unique control number based on the date the query was run using the format of [C77A][Date][Sequential Number] and opens a table of the newest control numbers but because for some reason running the Control Query creates duplicates of the numbers I added the Dup_Control Query to pull out only the unique numbers for a table without the duplicates.

I was hoping if someone could show me how to condense this or at least know why I get duplicates with the "Control Query".

Sample t1

```
DATE         | DATE_NUM| CONTROL_NUM   | UNIQUE_NUM
-------------------------------------------------------
C77A20140829 |  1      |C77A20140829001|20140829001
C77A20140829 |  1      |C77A20140829001|20140829001
C77A20140829 |  1      |C77A20140829001|20140829001
C77A20140829 |  1      |C77A20140829001|20140829001
C77A20140829 |  1      |C77A20140829001|20140829001
C77A20140829 |  1      |C77A20140829001|20140829001
C77A20140829 |  1      |C77A20140829001|20140829001
C77A20140829 |  2      |C77A20140829002|20140829002
C77A20140829 |  3      |C77A20140829003|20140829003
```

Sample t2

```
DATE         | DATE_NUM| CONTROL_NUM   | UNIQUE_NUM
-------------------------------------------------------
C77A20140829 |  1      |C77A20140829001|20140829001
C77A20140829 |  2      |C77A20140829002|20140829002
C77A20140829 |  3      |C77A20140829003|20140829003
```

Comment: Do you have a small sample of data where the Control Query creates duplicate unique numbers?

Comment: Yes I'll Edit the Original post to include it as well as a sample of the desired table

Comment: So, if you put the number 10 in the box and press the button, you want the DATE_NUM field to increment from 1 to 10, which would then make the UNIQUE_NUM field increment from 1 to 10?  Also, the Control query references a table called "t2".  Are the contents of "t2" what you have posted above?  Or will there just be a single field with a date in "t2"?

Comment: Yes, if 10 is entered into the box I'd want DATE_NUM and subsequently UNIQUE_NUM to increment from 1 to 10. The contents of "t2" is what is posted above. I'd like to make it so that I only get what is in "t2". Currently "t2" is linked to t1 via the "Dup_Cont" query by pulling all the unique entries from "t1" into "t2" so that there aren't any repeats in "t2" and the "Control" query uses "t2" to count how many entries have been made that day.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, [DATE] will never be equal to [DATE_A].  Your use fo the operator "LIKE" without any wildcards (*) means that the two **must** be equal for the incrementation to take place.  So, your Unique Number field will always end in "001".

You first will need to change that by adding a wildcard to the formula.  If that doesn't work, then try this method for incrementing a field:

[An Access query that returns every nth record](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/an-access-query-that-returns-every-nth-record/)